# Align cast menu item next to imageview in Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

[image: Toolbar]

I want to align the cast button menu item to the left of the imageview in the Toolbar, but I don't know how.

I added the cast button in menu_main.xml

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

The ImageView is in the layout xml from the Toolbar.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
android:layout_width="36dp"
android:layout_height="36dp"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/profile"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/profilepicture" />
```

How can I align the cast button to the left of the ImageView? Now it is added at the end of the toolbar on the right side of the ImageView

Comment: the only way create custom toolbar with imageView and overlayMenu items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess not possible as Official document says [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

> *One or more custom views.* The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. 
>   *An action menu.* **The menu of actions will pin to the end of the Toolbar** offering a few frequent, important or typical actions along with an optional overflow menu for additional actions.

**Alternative Solution would be :**
In menu.xml use custom layout `android:actionLayout` (ie ImageView) for menu Item.